# Adding block between category title and product list in the frontend

Tags: event-observer, blocks, category, frontend

I need to add my module's block between category title and product list inside the frontend category page.
I guess I'll have to use an event observer, but I can't find which, and what implementation to make.

Comment: you do not need to observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amit Bera is right, but his method can't be inside a proper module because it's rewriting Magento core files.
In fact, Magento does NOT allow a block to be between category title and product list (for a module). The block has to be before category's title, and then the layout must look like this :

```
  <catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="modulename/blockname" name="blockname" template="template.phtml" before="-"/>
    </reference>
  </catalog_category_default>
  <catalog_category_layered>
      <reference name="content">
        <block type="modulename/blockname" name="blockname" template="template.phtml" before="-"/>
      </reference>
  </catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 1):

**here add the code in your layout xml file**

```
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="category.products">
        <block type="core/template" name="yourblock" as="yourblock" template="page/myblock.phtml"  output="toHtml" before="product_list" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="category.products">
        <block type="core/template" name="yourblock" as="yourblock" template="page/myblock.phtml"  output="toHtml" before="product_list" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

**And also add the code in**

```
app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourtemplate/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

add the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('yourblock') ?>
```

after end of

```
   <div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
In Xml file   `type="core/template"` is `your block type`
and `page/myblock.phtml` is `your phtml file location`

Comment: I'm making a module that is meant to be exported. If I have to modify base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml, it won't be exportable.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: then view.phtml copy base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml, to yourPackage/yourtemplate/template/catalog/category/

Comment: What if someone who's using my module wants to use his own view.phtml template, for example using a theme ?

Comment: then they need to <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('yourblock') ?> to his own view.phtml...otherwise not possiable.but you set your view.phtml  to as category view  file using<reference name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>yourcatalog/view.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

Comment: So, if someone wants to use another module that personalize category view, this another module will take the step of the template ? So, not possible for magento to use 2 modules that personalize the same page ? And not possible to use a theme And a module at the same time?

Sorry for those questions, but now I really don't understand why developers are using CMS systems..

Comment: i cannot say anything about this... Sorry for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16336/discussion-between-yonn-trimoreau-and-amit-bera).